# Generate four random words from a list for XKCD-like passwords

Tags: text-processing, perl, random

For start, we know how can we output random lines from a txt file:

```
perl -MList::Util -e 'print List::Util::shuffle <>' words.txt
```

But we need a general solution (perl is usually installed on every unix-like OS) to output 4 random words from a txt file, how can we do it?

```
$ cat words.txt
...
alpha
beta
gamma
delta
epsilon
...
$
```

The "..." represents many other words.

Example output (without newline between them, but one unix newline is needed at the end, spaces should separate them):

```
$ perl SOMEMAGIC words.txt
gamma alpha delta beta
$
```

Using only perl, the shortest possible solution (oneliner).

It will be used as human memorable password generator: https://xkcd.com/936/

Since afaik perl is enough good to be named "random generator".

Example common english wordlist with 32768 unique lines: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/23726760/

Comment: Did you mean to post this on [codegolf.se]?

Comment: Otherwise, this feels like a general programming question (and so belonging on [so]), but it's also structured as a lazy "write my program" question that probably wouldn't be well-received.

Answer (score 6):

Perl is actually not such a good tool for this because you need a third-party library to generate random numbers securely. The default random number generator ([`rand`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rand.html) or anything else that uses the same source, such as `List::Util::shuffle`) is not suitable for anything related to security. If you want to use Perl, install [Math::Random::Secure](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Math%3A%3ARandom%3A%3ASecure) (and its dependencies) (`perl -MCPAN -eshell` and run `install Math::Random::Secure`).

```
perl -MMath::Random::Secure=rand -l -e '@words = <>; print map $words[rand(@words)], 1..4' words.txt
```

I suggest using Python instead. These days it's about as common as Perl, and its standard library is much better rounded. Yes, the code is longer, but short code is not in itself a sign of quality.

```
python -c 'import random, sys; rng = random.SystemRandom(); words = sys.stdin.readlines(); print " ".join([words[rng.randrange(0, len(words))].strip() for i in xrange(4)])' <words.txt
```

In a more readable multi-line form:

```
import random, sys
rng = random.SystemRandom()
words = sys.stdin.readlines()
print " ".join([words[rng.randrange(0, len(words))].strip() for i in xrange(4)])
```

Alternatively, if you have non-antique GNU coreutils, which is the case on non-embedded Linux and Cygwin, you can use the [`shuf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/shuf-invocation.html#shuf-invocation) utility. You need to pass a secure random generator with the `--random-source` option.

```
shuf --random-source=/dev/urandom -r -n 4 words.txt
```

Comment: testing the python oneliner, many-thanks!

Comment: A note from my personal experience: some of the dictionaries you may find online use `\r\n` as the line separator, and in this case you need to replace `:-1` with `:-2` or else you’ll get an extremely weird result.
Overall, it would have been much more reliable to use `.strip()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're not *against* non-Perl solutions, you just want something that works on most systems. In that case, the following uses only GNU core utils:

```
sort -R --random-source=/dev/urandom words.txt | head -n4 | paste -s -d' '
```

Modified to use `shuf`, based on Gilles' suggestion:

```
shuf -n 4 -r words.txt | paste -s -d' '
```

Comment: If you're going to rely on GNU coreutils, you might as well use `shuf` instead of this complex, slow pipeline. Using sort even introduces a small undesirable bias because it forbids repetition.

Comment: You need to pass `--random-source` with `shuf` as well. The default RNG is not seeded reliably.

Comment: "sort -R" is not random! try it with a testfile like: printf '1\n1\n2\n2\n' > a.txt

Comment: @halajoe `sort -R` is random (but with poorly-seeded entropy unless `--random-source` points to a good RNG) for inputs without duplicates.

Comment: You can use `xargs` without options instead of the `paste` invocation. Example using a secure random source and the words file: `shuf --head-count=4 --random-source=/dev/urandom /usr/share/dict/words | xargs`

Answer (score 1):

(ignoring the security problem mentioned by @Gilles)

```
 perl -0nE '@a=split; say join(" ", map{ $a[rand @a] } 1..4)'
```

or if you like CamelCase...

```
 perl -0nE '@a=split; say map{ ucfirst $a[rand @a] } 1..4'
```

Comment: Since you're mentioning "security problems", maybe you should point these out? It would help others if you additionally explained what the code is doing.

Comment: @Kusalananda The security problem is the one I mention in my answer: Perl's `rand` is not a secure RNG.